# Cell with Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

[image]

I have a UIImageView in custom cell ,Maximum size of UIImagView Can be 100X100. if there is no Image in UIImageView than its height should be Zero. How to specify constraint for this in xib?

Observer left cell image. "There is blank space of height 100 because cell does not have any image to display." There should not be any blank space between hello and heart button.

Right cell image is fine.There is image to display so cell is displaying it.and other component are coming below it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the image inside a div element and set the max-height css property to 100px.

Comment: this is not an html or css dude...you have to check tag before give an answer

Answer (score 0):

If an Iboutet is connected to the height constraint of the UIImageView then in the custom cell class you may check if there is image set the height constraint a value otherwise set to 0 and the heart and comment components should be pinned to image view.
So that on setting height constraint to 0, rest of the components move closer to "hello".

Comment: Thanks For Reply . Can you give me the code. I am not getting anything.